# Creating and maintaining a Redis session store replica in a nodejs expressjs app

Tags: node.js, session, redis, microservices, node-redis

Pretty much, I'm wondering how to create, and maintain a replica of a Redis session store in a Nodejs app with a microservices architecture.

**Short background (somewhat)**

I'm planning the architecture of a project I'm gonna start working on, and have decided to use Redis store for storing user sessions. I'm trying out a microservices architecture, and essentially, there's gonna be an authentication service that writes, and reads the to the session store as needed. What instantiating the store looks like usually:

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const redis = require('redis');
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

const { SESSION_OPTIONS } = require('./configs/session');

const app = express();


app.use(session({
    ...SESSION_OPTIONS,
    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redisClient })
}))
```

However, throughout my app, almost all user actions will have to be authorised, which involves checking user credentials stored in the session. Usually, in my monolithic projects, it looks something like:

```js
router.get('/someUserAction', ensureAuthorisation, (req, res) => {
    ...
})
```

where `ensureAuthorisation` is a function like:

```js
ensureAuthorisation: (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.user.isAuthorised) {
            return next();
    }
    return res.status(401).json({success: false, msg: 'fail msg'});
}
```

Because almost every user action will require authorisation, hence reads to the Redis sessions store, I'm assuming this wouldn't be good for the authentication service, that uses the same store but writes and reads less frequently. Thus, I want to create a separate service, the *authorisation* service, which uses its own Redis store. This store for the authorisation service should be a copy of the authentication service's store, removing, and updating sessions accordingly.

My initial thought was to have some form of asynchronous communication between both stores, with the authentication store writing new sessions to the authorisations... Question is, is this even possible, or would the copy store be more of a cache?

This was a bit long, and maybe confusing, so please ask any questions if you need further explanation (be kind to me pls lol). ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead using a single Redis only rather than creating a cache for other service.

use redis in sentinel mode, authorization service wirtes on the master and other read from the replicas.

Comment: How this be achieved using connect-redis, and node redis. I read on your suggestion of sentinel mode, and it seems like the ideal solution, but it doesn't seem like there's a way to implement that with what I'm currently using. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis you can try this , looks popular and supports sentinel mode